# foreach do not work when replacing elements of matrices

Tags: r, foreach

I'm Mr newbie. I dont understand the reason as to why foreach loops spit out a list of 1 when i run this code, instead of a list of the matrices with the replaced element:

```
a <- matrix(1:100,nrow=10,ncol=10)
loop_a <- foreach (i=1:5) %dopar%
{
a[a == 6] <- 1  
}
```

Comment: You are returning 1 here. Just return `a` instead?

Comment: but why am I returning 1? shouldnt i return a with 6 replaced by 1?

Comment: `\`<-\`(lhs, rhs)` is returning `rhs`, not `lhs`.

Comment: I see, Thank you.

Comment: Don't hesitate to answer to your own question.